# Modifying a record when a new entry is created

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently creating a database for a sort of game/reviewer based application. Whenever a user submits a review of a restaurant or such it adds points to his score. A summary of the SQL script would be:

```
CREATE TABLE user
    userid CHAR(30)
    user_name....
    userpoints largeint
    etc.
```

The table for the reviews is here:

```
    Restaurantid largeint (auto incrementing)
    restaurantname CHAR(30)
    etc.
```

How do I program the app to give the points whenever a review is posted?

Comment: Wherever your code posts the review, update the score. Alternatively, you may be able to use a MySQL trigger.

Comment: Whenever you do an `INSERT` from php into the review table, you also do an `UPDATE` in the user table to increment the score?

Answer (score 2):

Use a trigger that gets fired automatically on every insert in the `reviews` table:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER review_trigger AFTER INSERT ON `reviews`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   update user
   set userpoints = userpoints + 1
   where userid = NEW.reviewer;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

I assumed you have a column in your `reviews` table that relates to the user - I called it `reviewer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a [`Trigger`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) on the Review table that will insert into `user`, or create a [`Procedure`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html) to handle both inserts which then gets called by your application.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to do a bit of research into triggers. Triggers allow you to run SQL statements when records are selected, updated, inserted etc.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

You could create one of these triggers to run on insert into the review restaurant table, and have it update the users table to add 1 to the userpoints row for that user.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using triggers if you want the database to handle the problem or you would program it in php by using an insert query or update query.